# Nonlinear-Variation of Helmholtz Equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, coordinate-systems, laplacian

I was wondering on the solution of the equation $$\nabla^2P(\vec r)=v(\vec r)P(\vec r)^2\phantom{.......}(1)$$
Or more simply, if there exists a coordinate system where: $$\nabla^2P(\vec r)=P^2(\vec r)$$
Especially considering that if $\vec r=\xi_k$, a general orthonormal set of coordinates, then the Laplacian of such a coordiante system in Curvilinear coordinates is: $$\nabla^2f(\vec r)=\sum_i\frac{1}{\prod_k\sqrt{\hat{\bar g}_{kk}}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi_i}\left(\frac{\prod_k\sqrt{\hat{\bar g}_{kk}}}{\hat{\bar g}_{ii}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi_i}\right)$$

Comment: I'm not sure of the solution, but if you apply a Fourier transform to $\Delta u = u^2$ you'll obtain $| \xi|^2 \hat u = \hat u * \hat u$ where $f*g$ is the convolution of the functions. i.e. you may rephrase the PDE as an integral equation easily.

Comment: Well, that's, helpful Jeb, thanks anyways :)